# Is it possible to format/beautify Javascript in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm's option + command + L to format HTML, or python files is very convenient, but doesn't seem to work for JS, is this an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is (possible to format/beautify Javascript)!
The trick lies in [TextMate Bundles](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/12/feature-spotlight-textmate-bundles-in-pycharm/).  Below instructions are for Pycharm Community 2018.1.4

1)  Go to the [TextMate repo](https://github.com/textmate) and look for the [javascript tmbundle](https://github.com/textmate/javascript.tmbundle)
2)  Download the zip and unzip
3)  In Pycharm, go to `Settings -> Editor -> TextMate Bundles`
4)  Add new Bundle via the green `+` top right and select the `javascript.tmbundle-master` folder
5)  If you get the same yellow box that says `Some extensions declared in attached bundles are already used by native file types.`, then `Show details` -> `Unregister native file type`
6)  Pycharm will then re-index, which may take a long time.  After indexing is complete you should have javascript text highlighting.

[image]

Here is an [arbitrary code sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works to beautify js on windows in PyCharm Professional 2018.3:

1. Ensure your cursor is active inside the js file you want to beautify.
2. Alt + Ctrl + Shift + "L" to bring up the "Reformat File" popup
3. Select "whole file" radio button and checkboxes for "Rearrange code" and "Code Cleanup"

Comment: Works for linux as well